# MongoDB: Insert in nested array or upsert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, document, upsert

Update upsert is not working for a nested array. It returns an error that the query cannot be found.

My document:

```js
{
  _id: 60617172eca858909eace71f,
  marketId: '1.278363651',
  marketType: 'OVER_UNDER_15',
  runners: [
    {
      id: '113457',
      name: 'UNDER',
      updates: [
        { t: 1616998770482, p: 87.77 },
        // ...
      ]
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

My code:

```js
db.collection('markets').updateOne(
  {
    "marketId": "1.278363651",
    "runners.id": "113457",
  },
  {
    "$push": { "runners.$.updates": someUpdate }
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

If the market or the array does not exist, it does not create it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#upsert) says: "Do not use the positional operator $ with upsert operations because inserts will use the $ as a field name in the inserted document." - is this the problem you are facing? Is there any error when you do the update?

Comment: It says the query cannot be found. I need it to create both the document and the array